# Maclaurin series acting unusually

Tags: series-expansion

Here's my Mathematica code:

```
Tdelay = (Sqrt[m] Log[En/(En + V)])/(Sqrt[2] a Sqrt[En]);
In[15]:=Series[Tdelay, {En, 0, 1}] // Normal
Out[15]=-((Sqrt[En] Sqrt[m])/(Sqrt[2] a V)) + (Sqrt[m] Log[En/V])/(Sqrt[2] a Sqrt[En])
```

My question is why all of the terms contain the variable 'En'; isn't the first term in the Maclaurin series supposed to be $f(0)$ and that should be free of the variable 'En'. What am I not seeing?

Comment: it might have to do with the fact that $f(0)$ in your case is `Indeterminate`

Comment: @Nasser doubt it is, the first term of the series looks awfully similar to the original input and I believe all of the terms of the sequence may be Indeterminate if you compute them one by one.

Comment: `Series[f[x],{x,0,...}]` gives a powerseries not necessary starting with `f[0] x^0` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann where is the `x^0` term then and how does this command work?

Comment: @David Have a look in the documentation `Series can construct standard Taylor series, as well as certain expansions involving negative powers, fractional powers, and logarithms. `

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks. So its not a Taylor Series then.

Comment: @David Probably yes in your example! But be aware the Taylorseries ' Series[x^5,{x,0,11}]=x^5` has no term `x^0` too.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks. The problem was that I assumed that it was taking the Taylor series of the *entire* function, whereas I believe I see now that it is factoring the logarithm out of the function and taking its Taylor series. Thanks for the help!